# Keeping rows after the first non NaN in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in PANDAS with two columns and an index(dates). I would like to keep the rows after the first common non NaN element. For example, initially I have:

```
                    A      B        
        Index
        1/1/1950    NaN    5
        2/1/1950    7      NaN
        3/1/1950    9      NaN
        4/1/1950    NaN    6
        5/1/1950    4      15
        6/1/1950    2      21
        7/1/1950    NaN    5
        7/1/1950    12     5
        7/1/1950    5      NaN
```

and I would like to get

```
                    A      B        
        Index
        5/1/1950    4      15
        6/1/1950    2      21
        7/1/1950    NaN    5
        7/1/1950    12     5
        7/1/1950    5      NaN
```

since 5/1/1950 is the first time both A and B are not NaN, and I would like to keep all data after it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `notnull` on the df and test if all values in the row are `True` using `all(axis=1)`, we can then call `argmax` to get the first `True` index label and slice the df using `loc`:

```
In [37]:
df.loc[df.notnull().all(axis=1).argmax():]

Out[37]:
             A     B
Index               
5/1/1950   4.0  15.0
6/1/1950   2.0  21.0
7/1/1950   NaN   5.0
7/1/1950  12.0   5.0
7/1/1950   5.0   NaN
```

here is a breakdown:

```
In [38]:
df.notnull()

Out[38]:
              A      B
Index                 
1/1/1950  False   True
2/1/1950   True  False
3/1/1950   True  False
4/1/1950  False   True
5/1/1950   True   True
6/1/1950   True   True
7/1/1950  False   True
7/1/1950   True   True
7/1/1950   True  False

In [39]:
df.notnull().all(axis=1)

Out[39]:
Index
1/1/1950    False
2/1/1950    False
3/1/1950    False
4/1/1950    False
5/1/1950     True
6/1/1950     True
7/1/1950    False
7/1/1950     True
7/1/1950    False
dtype: bool

In [40]:
df.notnull().all(axis=1).argmax()

Out[40]:
'5/1/1950'
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @DSM it is more robust to use `df.loc[df.notnull().all(axis=1).cummax()]` as this will handle duplicate index values

Comment: This could fail depending on the index.  Something like `df.loc[df.notnull().all(axis=1).cummax()]` might be more robust.

Comment: @DSM what type of index would this fail for? You mean if it's float type or not sorted?

Comment: Say the first non-null was 7/1/1950.  When you select using `'7/1/1950':`, pandas has no way of knowing that you actually want to start from the *second* row with that index, so you wind up with the first row in your output having a NaN.

Comment: @DSM Ah yes I didn't notice that there were duplicates in the index here, will update